# Django APPEND_SLASH doesn't work properly

Tags: django, django-models

if i write `example.com/example-example` it is working.

However if i write `example.com/example-example/` it doesn't work

APPEND_SLASH=True in settings.py

```
  path('<slug:slug>',post_detail,name="post_detail"),
```

Comment: `APPEND_SLASH` means that if all the `path`/`url`s failed, and the path did not end with a slash, Django will add a slash and try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
path('<slug:slug>/',post_detail,name="post_detail"),
```

refer [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#example)